# Cannot read property 'name' of null on default value

Tags: reactjs

I have a state in which i have 
I had initialized my data state as null
For whole code visit

```
https://codeshare.io/5zMyXD
```

Calling aixos api request on componentDidMount

```
axios.post("http://localhost/axios1/index.php",data)
    .then(res=>this.setState({data:res.data}, 
()=>console.log(this.state.data)))
```

Getting this on state

```
{id: "1", name: "vivek", fname: "modi", mobile: "9024555623", photo: "http://localhost/axios1/uploaded/student/rhinoslider-sprite.png"}
fname: "modi"
id: "1"
mobile: "9024555623"
name: "vivek"
photo: "http://localhost/axios1/uploaded/student/rhinoslider-sprite.png"

<input defaultValue={this.state.data.name} />
```

how to set these values in it's input like input for name input for fname

Comment: If the object you have shown is your state then why do you try to access `this.state.data`? There is no such property in your state object. It probably should be `this.state.name` then.

Answer (score 0):

```
{id: "1", name: "vivek", fname: "modi", mobile: "9024555623", photo: "http://localhost/axios1/uploaded/student/rhinoslider-sprite.png"}
fname: "modi"
id: "1"
mobile: "9024555623"
name: "vivek"
photo: "http://localhost/axios1/uploaded/student/rhinoslider-sprite.png"

<input defaultValue={this.state.data.name} />
```

Just use name from state
as if the object you mentioned is state then you can directly access state keys from state
like
this.state.name || this.state.mobile

Comment: it's giving me null in value

Comment: if your this.state.data is what your printed then default value method of setting from state is right

Comment: If you can share the whole component it will much easier

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your code in order to get better help but
If you have a correct state you can change values like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value={this.state.data.name}>
```

But your state is null and the code you showed has problem, you need to fill your state correctly, in your class you can write:

```
State={name:"test"}
```

And it will work fine.  Hope this can help you

**update** now write this:

```
{this.state.data && this.state.data.name
    && ( < input defaultValue={this.state.data.name} /> )}
```

Comment: Using mobile at this moment, but will check it

Answer (score 0):

You can set like call your axios request through

```
componentDidMount(){
 axios.post("http://localhost/axios1/index.php",data)
 .then(res=>this.setState({data:res.data}, 
 ()=>console.log(this.state.data)))
}
```

Suppose you are getting this in your state

```
state={
 data:{
  id: "1", 
  name: "vivek", 
  fname: "modi", 
  mobile: "9024555623", 
  photo: "http://localhost/axios1/uploaded/student/rhinoslider-sprite.png"
 }
}
```

and then render it as

```
render(){
  const {name,fname} = this.state.data?this.state.data:"";

  return(
   <div>
        <input defaultValue={this.state.name} />
        <input defaultValue={this.state.fname} />
   </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: change line number 31 this.setState({res.data},()=>console.log(this.state))

Answer (score -1):

Change this in your code, line no 31

```
this.setState({res.data},()=>console.log(this.state))
```

Comment: it's giving me Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: can you share the full trace

Comment: Line 26:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  24 |   data.append("func","editData");
  25 |   axios.post("http://localhost/axios1/index.php",data)
> 26 |   .then(res=>this.setState({res.data},()=>console.log(this.state)))
     |                                ^
  27 |  }
  28 |  setVal(e){
  29 |   if(e.target.name==='name'){

Comment: arrow is coming on res.data

Comment: remove then clause and add this  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => this.setState({json},()=>console.log(this.state));
  });

Comment: It's giving me res.json is not a function

Comment: try to remove first then clause then try

Comment: now it's giving me Cannot read property 'id' of null and you have lot's of error in you .then code link ;} after console.log(this.state) and

Comment: check from where your id is coming and after successfully fetching the api at what node of state are you saving the response

Comment: Now i have a proper data in state because if i console the this.state.data in componentDidMount then it's working fine then if i console this.state.data.name then it's giving me proper data but if i write defaultValue in input filed and use this.state.data.name then it's saying  Cannot read property 'name' of null and if i just give this.state.data in defaultValue then its giving me [object Object]

Comment: add this line after render() and before return, try to check both line                     const name = this.state.data?this.state.data.name :"nothing";                             
 const name = this.state.name?this.state.name :"nothing"; and add defaultValue={name}